# SVN checksums comparison

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, checksum

I'm using VisualSVN Server and Tortoise SVN client. I need to compare file checksum in working copy between SVN server's file checksum.
I get checksum of working copy file from `svn info`:

```
C:\PATH>svn info FILE.xml
...
Checksum: bd9c64f72240de72e06ffe1f562c6a6467d08071
```

But how can i get the file checksum on SVN Server itself? If i use `svn info` to https (where my SVN server is), i don't get the checksum:

```
C:\PATH>svn info https://svnsrv:8443/svn/Projects/PATH/FILE.xml
Path: FILE.xml
Name: FILE.xml
URL: https://svnsrv:8443/svn/Projects/PATH/FILE.xml
Relative URL: ^/PATH/FILE.xml
Repository Root: https://svnsrv:8443/svn/Projects
Repository UUID: e6ccef74-f44d-e74c-9476-7af031b83d22
Revision: 5236
Node Kind: file
Size in Repository: 1081199
Last Changed Author: Administrator
Last Changed Rev: 5234
Last Changed Date: 2021-06-03 16:15:36 +0300
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the actual issue you are trying to solve? Why do you want to compare the checksum manually? Aren't you trying to reinvent SVN working copy status?

Comment: The issue is simply to show on the screen checksums of working copy files and server files which are different =) Those are the project requirements...

Comment: If we're talking about the same revision, the only circumstances I can think of where that could happen is when you're using `svn:eol-style` to alter line endings, the file has local modifications or the working copy is corrupted. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if working copy has actual revision, but some local file is changed, i get checksums this way: working copy checksum by `svn info FILE.xml` and checksum of changed local file by powershell `Get-FileHash FILE.xml -Algorithm SHA1`. I need to compare files if the issue, which i mentioned in comment below, happened.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to compare file checksum in working copy between SVN server's
> file checksum.

Checksum provided by `svn info FILE.xml` is the actual checksum of the file present in the Subversion repository at the revision to which your working copy or the particular file is updated to. Checksum in the command's output will remain the same if you change the file in your working copy and run the command again. Therefore, you could compare the file's checksum with the checksum from the `svn info FILE.xml` output.

Checksum displayed is the checksum of the pristine version of the file (aka BASE) which is stored in the working copy's administrative area (single hidden `.svn` directory at the root of your working copy).

Note that you could rely on the [working copy's status](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/status/) to determine if the local version of the file has modifications. See [TortoiseSVN Manual | Getting Status Information](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html), too.

Comment: Thanks! i already have the working copy's status control on my machines. I just got stuck with the issue, how to get checksum of the committed file on some machine. Maybe there is the way to trace which machine was commit from? If i knew that, i could probably call svn info to \\ClientWhereCommitHappened\PATH\FILE.xml and get the actual checksum.